# Call AIR Application method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air

I have an Adoboe AIR (ActionScript) application that embeds an HTML page using the AIR HTML component. I would like to add communication between the two: E.g. I would like to call a method within the AIR Application from the Javascript within the HTML page in the HTML component etc... Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance,
Jon.